# PHP Laravel: Update one -to- many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, one-to-many

I have a one to many relationship in my Eloquent model and would like to know the best approach to go about updating the model, especially the `belongsTo` model part.

I have come across other answers that suggest that I do save each `belongsTo` model singly, but that brings up a problem as I will be making `n` amount of calls to the database server instead of a single insert or a few.

So I will like to know the best approach to ensure my query and database resourse is optimized and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

hasOne / hasMany (1-1, 1-M)
    1. save(new or existing)
    2. saveMany(array of models new or existing)

Use any of these two methods..